# Is there a way to use reserved javascript keywords as Object keys in ejs?

Tags: javascript, express, ejs

Is there a way to use a reserved keyword such as `void` as an object key in ejs?

I was trying to pass an object as the view data which had `void`(a javascript reserved keyword) as a key.

```
const viewData = {
  void: {
    someKey: 'some value',
    someOtherKey: 'some other value',
  },
}
```

But, when I try to access this `void` key in ejs as follow:

```
<h3><%= void.someKey %></h3>
```

It throws an error

```
Unexpected token . in <FILEPATH>
```

Is there any way to access this void object in ejs without having to rename it?
I tried to access it using `this.void` but that did not work.

Comment: can you use computed properties in EJS in some way? Perhaps some form of `["void"]` would work but I'm not familiar with EJS, so I can't say for certain.

Comment: `<%= locals["void"].someKey %>`?

Comment: Thanks @WiktorZychla That did the trick. Although that bracket notation is not needed, normal dot notation `locals.void.someKey` will work fine. Can you post this as an answer so that I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer accepted by the OP (in a comment under the question) involves the `locals` object:

```
<%= locals["void"].someKey %>
```

This supposedly also works

```
<%= locals.void.someKey %>
```